# What is the Difference Between Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK and Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH? The output is same every time

Tags: java, date, java.util.calendar

I'm setting time using `Timestamp` class with current time. I'm setting the time with the `Calendar` class first by `DAY_OF_WEEK` and second with `DAY_OF_MONTH`. I’m getting the same output every time. Then what is the diffrence between `DAY_OF_MONTH` and `DAY_OF_WEEK`?

```
    Timestamp followUpDateBegins = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(followUpDateBegins);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -30);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    followUpDateBegins.setTime(cal.getTime().getTime());
    System.out.println("followUpDateBegins      "+followUpDateBegins);
```

OR

```
    Timestamp followUpDateBeginsSecond = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    cal.setTime(followUpDateBeginsSecond);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    followUpDateBeginsSecond.setTime(cal.getTime().getTime());
    System.out.println("followUpDateBegins" + followUpDateBeginsSecond);
```

Comment: What's the difference? They are completely different things. The day of the month today is 10. The day of the week today is Tuesday, which is represented in `Calendar` by [`TUESDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#TUESDAY), the number 3.

Comment: It might not make a difference in your case when you use the `add` method on an existing date, but it certainly would if you used the `set` method.

Comment: Why do you want to bother? Both `Timestamp` and `Calendar` are long outdated, and today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And the modern classes can be saved to your SQL database (through JDBC or JPA, for example) just like we did with `Timestamp` in the old days.

Comment: @OleV.V.sometimes, unfortunately, it's not up to you, even if you're right... working with GWT for instance, i don't event **have** the Calendar API, juste `Date`!

Comment: First try the [JAVADOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and then something simple like `System.out.println("week: " + cal.get(DAY_OF_WEEK) + ", month: " + cal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH));`

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DAY_OF_WEEK is the day of the week (7 days), DAY_OF_MONTH is the day of the month (<=31 days)

Comment: No problem. Don't hesitate to read the `Calendar` Javadoc, I find it very understandable and comprehensive. Even though it's quite and outdated API, it's still quite powerful and easy to handle.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `add`

`cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -30);`  is the same as  `cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30);`

Also DATE and DAY_OF_YEAR will act the same - because you modify Days in both cases and you just go 30 days behind.

But if your calendar is set to 15th of April for example and you do
`cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` and `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` they will return different results.

Comment: Well explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the other answers, adding both fields results in the same date, which is a bizarre implementation detail, IMO. We can see that [from the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#1032), there's a `switch` statement where both fields are considered "the same" when adding:

```
case DAY_OF_MONTH: // synonym of DATE
case DAY_OF_YEAR:
case DAY_OF_WEEK:
```

Alghough it doesn't make sense "adding days of week" (IMHO - because in the end you just add **days**, no matter if it's in the same week, month or whatever, and that's it), that's the way it's implemented. This API is really confusing...

Another detail is that `Calendar.getInstance()` **already returns the current date/time** - [it internally calls `System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#627), so creating a `Timestamp` just to set it in the calendar is redundant. You could just do:

```
// create the calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// do your stuff
...

// create the timestamp
Timestamp followUpDateBeginsSecond = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```